# When does catalogrule_product_price table get updated in relation to the product save in Magento?

Tags: magento, events, observers

I'm trying to log some simple data every time a product is saved such as price and catalog rule prices.  I have set up my module to work off the `catalog_product_save_after` event and everything seems to be working fine except the catalogrule price which is pulling the price PRIOR to the save.

To test I have tried sticking in a direct MySQL query of the `catalogrule_product_price` table, but it appears the values in there haven't been updated based on the last change when I query it.  After the save I check MySQL directly and it is updated as expected.

I found the `replace into` statement in `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Mysql4_Rule::_saveRuleProductPrices()`, but when I tried placing my direct sql query right after the `$this->_getWriteAdapter()->query($query);` I'm still getting the old catalog rule price.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**From part of the module's config.xml...**

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>

        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <mycompany_productlog_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MyCompany_ProductLog_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
                </mycompany_productlog_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>

    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

**Part of the call from the etc/modules/MyCompany_All.xml...**

```
<MyCompany_ProductLog>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
    <depends>
        <Mage_CatalogRule />
    </depends>
</MyCompany_ProductLog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, this turned out to be an issue with the old code I was using to pull the data from SQL. When I updated our methods to query properly everything worked as expected.  Oops!